# listing all the airlines from united sates mapreduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

The below mapreduce code is written to get the following output:

> "Princeton Aviation Corporation"
>
> "Priority Air Charter"
>
> "Priority Air Transport"   "Priority Aviation Company"
>
> "Private Jet Expeditions"  "Private Jet Management"

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class UScountry {

    public static class mymapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,Text>{

        protected void map(Object key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

            String data[]=value.toString().split(",");
            CharSequence c="united states";
            if(data[6].toLowerCase().contains(c)){
                context.write(new Text(data[1]),new Text("") );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException
    {
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        Job job=Job.getInstance(conf,"US");
        job.setJarByClass(UScountry.class);
        job.setMapperClass(mymapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }



}
```

But output the code is giving is:

> "Princeton Aviation Corporation"  0
>
> "Priority Air Charter"    0
>
> "Priority Air Transport"  0
>
> "Priority Aviation Company"   0
>
> "Private Jet Expeditions" 0
>
> "Private Jet Management"  0

Please help me find out where am I going wrong!

Input file is:

> 1,"Privilege Style L",\N,"","PVG","PRIVILEGE","Spain","N"
>
> 2,"Princeton Aviation Corporation",\N,"","PCN","PRINCETON","United
>   States","N"
>
> 3,"Priority Air Charter",\N,"","PRY","PRIORITY AIR","United
>   States","N"
>
> 4,"Priority Air Transport",\N,"","PAT","PAT","United States","N"
>
> 5,"Priority Aviation Company",\N,"","BCK","BANKCHECK","United
>   States","N"
>
> 6,"Privatair",\N,"","PTI","PRIVATAIR","Switzerland","Y"
>
> 7,"Private Jet Expeditions",\N,"","PJE","PEE JAY","United States","N"
>
> 8,"Private Jet Management",\N,"","PJA","PRIVATE FLIGHT","United
>   States","N"
>
> 9,"Private Wings Flugcharter",\N,"8W","PWF","PRIVATE
>   WINGS","Germany","N"

Answer (score 1):

You may set `NullWritable.class` for the output value class.

```
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
```

This will suppress the value part of the reducer output, which is 0's in your output.

Comment: its still giving the same output, even after doing the changes you suggested

Comment: Can you check if you have the same code as in question?

I ran the code you have given here with `Text.class` as output value class and it isn't giving 0s, but an extra space after each name.
"Princeton Aviation Corporation" 
"Priority Air Charter" 
"Priority Air Transport" 
"Priority Aviation Company" 
"Private Jet Expeditions" 

With `NullWritable.class` as output value class, I get clean output - Just the names.
"Princeton Aviation Corporation"
"Priority Air Charter"
"Priority Air Transport"
"Priority Aviation Company"
"Private Jet Expeditions"
"Private Jet Management"

Comment: Yes it worked! I made new java file with same code. Might be the problem of my jar getting replaced while execution

Comment: I see that you have `IntWritable` in the imports. This could be because, you may have had `IntWritable.class` as output class at one point and your JAR was created with that version of code. If you think this works, please mark the question answered.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
context.write(new Text(data[1]),new Text("") );
```

to this:

```
context.write(new Text(data[1]));
```

Comment: its showing me error:The method write(Text, Text) in the type TaskInputOutputContext<Object,Text,Text,Text> is not applicable for the arguments (Text)

Comment: This won't work - `write` needs to be given a key and a value.